# Selenium IDE gotoIF comparing vchar strings

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

I have tried the following

```
gotoIf "${oneoff}"=="Jeff Della Rosa" 
gotoIf ${oneoff}=="Jeff Della Rosa" 
gotoIf ${oneoff}=={"Jeff Della Rosa"} <-- not sure why, just trying anything.
```

-------- HERE IS THE WHOLE sequence----------

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct format is.

```
gotoIf '${oneoff}'=='Jeff Della Rosa'
```

Single quotes...  Grr!

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, for testing for "NOT EQUAL" use this syntax:

`gotoIf '${variable}'!='the string operand' target_label`

Having single quotes around both the variable and the operand IS important.

Comment: The quotes on both ends of the expression was useful